# Can you edit/mod the rate of Strategic Resource generation in Civilization III?

Tags: civilization-3

When playing Civ 3 (The "complete" edition on Steam), I often find that the Strategic Resources don't appear nearly frequently enough for my liking. In an area that could fit 10 or 11 cities without any overlap, there was a single patch of Iron. When you add in that a resource can be depleted, this makes the ability to play out the map fairly unpredictable (since you can't see resources for techs you don't have).

Is there some way to edit the map generator's strategic resource frequency? Or a mod or patch or something that does this? I'd like them to appear more often without having to use a custom map to do it.